# TortoiseSVN plugin for Rally?

Tags: tortoisesvn, rally, tortoisegit

I looking for TortosieSVN plugin which can connect to Rally Software and allow select defects from commit dialog and bound them with revision.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it exists: https://github.com/azarkevich/TortoiseRally

I share it recently for public access.